# How to pause and resume rotate animation android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-animation

I have implemented image rotate animation on the audio player screen where when audio start than image rotation and when a user clicks on pause button animation stop, I use clearAnimation() method for stopping animation and when user resume I call startAnimation() method but this Look bad because when I clear animation image degree like 90 was different and when I startAnimation() again its starting point was 0. please check this video where animation having an issue while play/pause audio [Watch This Video](https://streamable.com/5ahmi).

So I find a pause()/resume() animation for better smoothness. Can anyone help me to sort out animation smoothness or working batter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Animator` object to animate the view's property (like `android:rotation`):

```
View imgView = findViewById(R.id.image);
View playPauseBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);

final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgView, View.ROTATION, 0f, 90f)
        .setDuration(4000);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.start();

playPauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (anim.isPaused()) {
            anim.resume();
        } else {
            anim.pause();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Bro, I still have an issue while resuming an animation see this video.
https://streamable.com/2abqw

Comment: Optimize your Image and enable hardware acceleration (if possible). [check this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#layers-anims)

Comment: I just create its demo for that image and its working fine.
But when ever I connect that animation or pause/resume on audio player(service class) its not resume animation smoothly.
Do you have any idea on this?